# HTML print the whole page plus a PDF

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, printing

I have an ASP.NET project where I have divs in the size of DIN A4 with text and at the end a two page long PDF in an object. I want to print all at once with a button. I'm as far, that I have two print menues open, but it should be one. Part of my Code:

```
<script>
function printPage() {
    window.print();
    document.getElementById("printPDF").print();
}</script>
<button type="button" class="printButton" onclick="printPage()" style="margin-top:5mm;margin-bottom:2mm;">
print
</button>
<object class="printButton" id="printPDF" width="800" height="2250" type="application/pdf" data="name.pdf">
</object>
```

The class "printButton" is there cause the PDF print as empty page, when i use window.print.

```
@media print{
.printButton{
    display:none;
}}
```

I am a javascript beginer with less than two hours experience. If you have a asp.net c# alternative I would take that, too. Thanks

Comment: The result has to work with the internet explorer.